# Autohotkey - Barcode Macro - How to trigger a script if a certain barcode was scanned?

Tags: macros, triggers, barcode, autohotkey

I would like to create barcode macros - if the user scans a certain barcode, that would run a script. The barcode can be any character string, just to trigger the script. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is a barcode string? Please be more descriptive and include your code you have problems with.

Comment: There is no string yet. What I would like to create is a list of barcodes (eg: barcode 1 = sd2DK43AF6Fkfs, barcode 2 = lkfdSr4fdsAS, etc.). If the user scans barcode 1 that would automatically runs a script, if he scans barcode 2 that would run a different script, and if he scans anything else, then nothing would happen, the barcode scanner would operate as normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run a script based on a specific input (e.g. keyboard) do this:

Example of scanned string: asdkffasdf

```
:?*:asdkffasdf::
    SoundBeep, 500,500
    MsgBox, String asdkffasdf has been scanned
Return
```

Comment: I'll give it a try on Monday. But it's promising :)

Comment: Robert's answer is a 'hotstring' which will be triggered when that string is typed into the keyboard. Your problem will likely be how to interface the script with your 'scanned' barcode. What happens when a barcode is 'scanned'? How is the string/stored displayed?

Comment: @Mikew, I know that. That is why I wrote that "I hope this works with the Barcode reader".

Comment: It does work! The only issue is with the barcode scanner behaviour. So if it's a CR (enter) then you need to disable the Enter key input for the time you scan the code.

Comment: And have you solved the issue with the CR or do you need assistance?

Comment: The question mark in the example code allows the script to start immediately, without an ending character. You can define which ending character you want to use. When you remove the question mark, the ending character(s) will be in effect again. The normal ending characters are: #Hotstring EndChars -()[]{}:;'"/\,.?!'n 't. 'n is for new line (maybe 'r for CR will work as well). P.s. the `'` character is in reality the sign under the ~, but that character is used here as a format character, so I can't use it.