# How can I trigger/run an autohotkey script by scanning a barcode?

Tags: autohotkey

I have a barcode scanner plugged into a keyboard input on the back of my computer tower and I'd like to be able to scan an item, have it catch the barcode and have it go through a script.

Is there any way to figure out the name of the device/keyboard inputs coming from and have a if input from deviceb then do... ?

Thanks

Comment: Do your barcodes have something predictable (e.g. fixed prefix/suffix,length+e.g. {Enter}). AHK will have trouble differentiating between a normal keyboard and a barcode scanner. There are some people who have tried to differentiate between HID's in AHK, but it is not easy. If you have a fixed length, you can test if you received all characters within e.g. 30 ms (this would only give trouble when you paste the right number of char. with an {Enter} included)

Comment: Not predictable, aside from speed of entry, I'm thinking mostly I need HID differentiation and catching of upc help, working from the ahk block of code entitled barcode watcher.

Comment: Most scanners can be configured to send prefixes and suffixes. With the scanners I use, you can print out a sheet of barcodes for different configuration settings and then scan them to enable/disable them. Check the scanner's manual for the option to set a unique prefix.

Answer (score 1):

This has been discussed on the autohotkey forums.
http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/54958-barcode-scanner-watch/

```
Loop 10
Hotkey, % "$~" A_Index-1, BarCodeHandler, on
BarCodeHandler:
Accu .= SubStr(A_ThisHotkey, 0)
If Strlen(Accu) > 8 && A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < 60
   SetTimer, TheBigShebang, -60
If (A_TimeSincePriorHotkey > 100)
   Accu := SubStr(A_ThisHotkey, 0)
return
TheBigShebang:
If Accu
   msgbox You scanned barcode %Accu%
return
```

this creates a hotkey for all numbers 0-9 and will pop a messagebox if the length if of a certain size (8) and the time since prior number key was pressed is less than 60.

The above handles the generic case of looking for any barcode.

If you are interested in just executing actions upon a specific barcode, no need for the complexities.  Just define a hotkey for the specific code in your ahk script, as mentioned here.

[Autohotkey - Barcode Macro - How to trigger a script if a certain barcode was scanned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177112/autohotkey-barcode-macro-how-to-trigger-a-script-if-a-certain-barcode-was-sc)

```
:?*:SPECIFIC_CODE::
    SoundBeep, 500,500
    MsgBox, String SPECIFIC_CODE has been scanned
    Return
```

Differentiating between the keyboard and the barcode scanner is something that could also be done, which requires a bit of code which is available with a write up and codeproject links with supporting material as well.
http://ase.com.ua/c-keyboard-intercept-blocking-redirect.html

[Keyboard Redirector](http://nate.deepcreek.org.au/dev/keyboardredirector.rails)
Uses the windows RawInput API to determine which keyboard a keystroke is from and allows you to block the keystroke from the focussed application

I have a personal project called HIDHelve which may also be of interest. 
http://dave.thehorners.com/tech-talk/projects-research/hidhelve

Comment: I've been experimenting with that block of code but it still sends the barcode in whatever's open on the computer, where I'd rather it catch it and run the script with the upc in a variable... (which would launch my gui window with the csv search result)